# Are tensorflow random values guaranteed to be the same inside a single run?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

For `tf.random_uniform` and similar random ops I understand that "The random ops are stateful, and create new random values each time they are evaluated.", and therefore I get different values when calling `session.run()` twice:

```
# Each time we run these ops, different results are generated
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(norm))
print(sess.run(norm))
```

My question is, if my graph refers to a random op twice, is it guaranteed that the two "calls" will see the same value inside a single `run()`? E.g.

```
rnd_source = tf.random_normal(...)
x1 = rnd_source + 0.
x2 = rnd_source * 1.
sess.run([x1, x2])
```

If it is not guaranteed that `x1` and `x2` will have the same values, is there an easy way to store the random value in a tensor (not a tf.Variable) to ensure that the random op is evaluated only once? If it *is* guaranteed that `x1` will have the same values as `x2`, is there a way to force re-evaluation of the random op inside a single run to get new random values?

Comment: You can usually get random values to be repeatably the same by seeding your random generator appropriately. However the internals of tensorflow do not guarantee repeatability, especially with gpu. This has typically to do with small precision error from not exactly associative addition on floats that snowball and make different runs diverge away as soon as a minute difference appears.

Comment: Reproducibility of TensorFlow functionality when running on GPUs has recently been significantly enhanced, and development is ongoing. Please see the OSS [tensorflow-determinism](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism) repo for the latest status and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done that without realizing it. Just assign the value to a tensor and then use that value:

```
rnd_source = tf.random_normal((1,))
m = rnd_source
```

Now, at every run, `m` evaluates to a single draw from the normal distribution, and then you draw other graphs from it:

```
In [27]: for i in range(10):
    ...:     a, b, c, d, e = sess.run( [m*1, m+0, m+1, m+2, m+3 ]  )
    ...:     print(a, b, c, d, e)

[-2.1935725] [-2.1935725] [-1.1935725] [-0.19357252] [0.8064275]
[-0.5607107] [-0.5607107] [0.43928927] [1.4392893] [2.4392893]
[0.17031813] [0.17031813] [1.1703181] [2.1703181] [3.1703181]
[0.05647242] [0.05647242] [1.0564724] [2.0564723] [3.0564723]
[-0.2119268] [-0.2119268] [0.7880732] [1.7880732] [2.7880733]
[-0.07041783] [-0.07041783] [0.9295822] [1.9295821] [2.929582]
[-0.9486307] [-0.9486307] [0.05136931] [1.0513693] [2.0513692]
[1.3629643] [1.3629643] [2.3629642] [3.3629642] [4.362964]
[1.6997207] [1.6997207] [2.6997209] [3.6997209] [4.699721]
[1.480969] [1.480969] [2.480969] [3.480969] [4.480969]
```

Now, every time you go through your training loop, you will get a new value from the distribution, but, create the rest of the graph using `m`, and that will be consistent ...

To clarify further, lets add new nodes ...

```
In [28]: n = m+0
In [29]: o = m+1
```

Now,

```
In [31]: for i in range(10):
    ...:     a, b = sess.run([n, o])
    ...:     print(a, b)
    ...:
[0.32054538] [1.3205454]
[-0.6587958] [0.34120423]
[-0.8067821] [0.19321787]
[-0.29313084] [0.7068691]
[-1.1867933] [-0.18679333]
[1.4355402] [2.4355402]
[0.45581594] [1.4558159]
[-1.9583491] [-0.9583491]
[-1.2682568] [-0.26825678]
[1.534502] [2.534502]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. For avoidance of doubt, if I'm not using `m` to create the rest of the graph, but `rnd_source`, will the value be guaranteed to be the same, too? After all, `rnd_source = tf.random_normal((1,)); m = rnd_source; n = m + 0; o = m + 1` should really be equivalent to `rnd_source = tf.random_normal((1,)); n = rnd_source + 0; o = rnd_source + 1` as `m` and `nrd_source` should point to the same tensor?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I should have seen that!